# R shiny format background color of two cells within datatable

Tags: r, shiny, background-color, dt

I have a datatable (myTable) which is simply a 2x2 datatable (2 rows and 2 columns)

I want to format the background color of only 2 cells within the datatable:

Cell[1,2] should always be green (first row, second column)

Cell[2,1] should always be red (second row, first column)

This is as far as I've got

Any ideas would be appreciated

```
    formatStyle(
      myTable, 
      columns = c(1,2),
      fontWeight = 'bold',
      backgroundColor = ????,
      border = '2px solid #ddd'
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it help ?

```
library(DT)
changeCellColor <- function(i, j, color){
  color <- sprintf("'%s'", color)
  c(
    "function(row, data, num, index){",
    sprintf("  var i = [%s], j = [%s], color = [%s];", 
            toString(i-1), toString(j), toString(color)),
    "  var n = i.length;",
    "  for(let k=0; k < n; k++){",
    "    if(index == i[k]){",
    "      $('td:eq(' + j[k] + ')', row)",
    "        .css({'background-color': color[k]});",
    "    }",
    "  }",
    "}"  
  )
}
datatable(iris[1:5,], 
          options = list(
            dom = "t",
            rowCallback = JS(changeCellColor(c(1,2), c(2,1), c("blue","red")))
          )
)
```